# How to solve these Haskell Kind errors

Tags: haskell, types

So I've been messing around with Haskell, and I've come across this strange error in my code.
" 'IO' is not applied to enough type arguments
   Expected kind '?', but 'IO' has kind '*->*'
   In the type signature for 'loop': loop :: State -> IO"

**Here is the Code**

```
import System.IO
data State = State [Int] Int Int deriving (Show)

main = do
   loop (State [] 0 0)

loop::State -> IO
loop state = do
   putStr "file: "
   f <- getLine
   handle <- openFile f ReadMode
   cde <- hGetContents handle
   hClose handle
   putStrLn cde
   loop state
```

How do I fix this error? Also, any insight on kinds would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Wikipedia: Kind (type theory)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kind_(type_theory))

Answer (score 11):

`IO` is a [type constructor](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Constructor#Type_constructor), not a full type. You should declare

```
loop :: State -> IO ()
```

where `()` is the *unit type*; the type with only one value, also spelled `()`. That's the appropriate type for an eternal loop or any other function that does not return a (meaningful) value.

Answer (score 11):

`IO` is a *type constructor*, which means that it  needs an argument in order to become a type.  So:

```
IO Int
IO String
IO ()
```

are types, but `IO` by itself is not.

The *kind* of `IO` is `* -> *`, which is like saying it is a function that takes a type and returns a type.

I would suggest changing

```
loop :: State -> IO
```

to

```
loop :: State -> IO ()
```

(`()` is the "unit type", it has only one value (also called `()`), and is typically used where `void` would be used in C-like languages)

Answer (score 4):

As others have mentioned, `IO` is a type constructor, not a type. So you have to apply it to some other type. A value of type `IO Foo` means that it is a computation which potentially does some I/O and then returns a value of type `Foo`.

luqui and larsman suggested that you should use `()` as a return value. I think the following type is a better alternative for a function that loops forever:

```
loop :: String -> IO a
```

Note that the function now is polymorphic in the return value. This type is much more informative than having it return `()`. Why? Because a function of this type *must* be a looping function. There is no way to implement a terminating function with this type. A user of this function will see immediately from the type that it is a looping function. So you get some documentation for free with this type.

Comment: Yeah that's the type I wanted to give it too.  I suggested `()` for simplicity, but thanks for putting it here.

Comment: Why does this have to be a looping function if it returns IO a?

Comment: Well, it doesn't have to be looping.  It could also throw an exception.  But if the return type uses a type variable that's not used elsewhere in the signature, that means the function can't terminate normally.